# How must be the interaction between two systems in order to have entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

My question is **which characteristics must the interaction between two systems have in order to have entanglement ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only interaction hamiltonian which will not generate entanglement instantly between system A and system B is one of the form

$$H = H_A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes H_B$$

Which is exactly a Hamiltonian that has no interaction between system A and B. Entanglement is hand-in-hand with interaction, and it is not some kind of special thing that only happens with specially chosen circumstances. Thus particles are constantly getting entangled all the time.